# how can I change my font color for Shortcode

Tags: shortcode

Both background and text color of my website are black. so the audience can't see what are they writing. I want to change the text color to white but I don't know how can I do it! 
As there is a code in my Shortcode:

`[contact-form-7 id="6085" title="Contact form 1"]`

I don't know what should I do to change the color or the texts?

Comment: Most likely the form, generated by the shortcode has a specific class attribute, so you can target it via CSS to change its font color.

Comment: As @birgire said above you can change it via CSS but if you don't know how to do it then just share the p[age URL from your site where it is displaying so that i can help you to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Contact form 7 uses the `wpcf7-form` class for it's forms and `wpcf7` for it's parent DIV. You can set the color of the input types by these CSS rules:

```
.wpcf7-form input[type="text"],
.wpcf7-form input[type="url"],
.wpcf7-form input[type="password"],
.wpcf7-form input[type="email"],
.wpcf7-form textarea {
    color:white !important
}
```

The `!important` rule will make it override any other style's rules. Head over to `Appearance > Customize` and add the above rules to your custom CSS.

**PS :** You can also use `.wpcf7 input[type="text"]` if your form's class is different for any reason.